# Problem getting value from DatagridView cell

Tags: c#, charts

I have a DataGridView that is bound to a DataTable. The data in the DataTable is shown in a chart(I am using Microsoft Charting). After a user edits a cell in the DataGridView the value is validated then saved in the DataTable. This is done automatically(the databinding mechanism takes care of this) and works just fine.

My problem is the following: I need to send the value to the DataTable when the user presses a key, without taking the cell out of edit mode. I need this so I can update the chart in a "real-time" way.

I've tried something like this:

```
    void infoDataGridView_EditingControlShowing(object sender, DataGridViewEditingControlShowingEventArgs e)
    {
        e.Control.KeyUp += new KeyEventHandler(Control_KeyUp);          
    }

    void Control_KeyUp(object sender, KeyEventArgs e)
    {
        this.Validate();
        UpdateChart();
    }
```

This is part of the code belonging to the form.
But this takes out the current cell from edit mode. Maybe I could manually set the value in the datatable but in `Control_KeyUp` I have no idea which cell is being edited.

If you have better ideas please don't hesitate to share them. :)

Answer (score 1):

Use CurrentCellDirtyStateChanged event

```
private void dataGridView1_CurrentCellDirtyStateChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
   if(dataGridView1.IsCurrentCellDirty)
   {
      dataGridView1.CommitEdit(DataGridViewDataErrorContexts.Commit);
   }
}
```

This sends the cells value to the DataTable without bringing the cell out of edit.

Comment: I think this might only work for the first character changed in the cell though... Once the dirty state is dirty, it's dirty.  This code wouldn't be called for each keypress, would it?

Comment: The CommitEdit sets dataGridView1.IsCurrentCellDirty to false and any subsequent edits set the cell as dirty again so that the changes are directly sent to the table.

Comment: Oh nice - that's pretty elegant.  Does it keep the DGV in edit mode though?  What about the cursor (does it get reset each time)?

Comment: It makes the update to the DataSet seamlessly, edit mode and cursor doesn't change. The event get's called twice though, on extra time when the dirty state is set to false, but you could check dgv.IsCurrentCellDirty to prevent the unnecessary call.

Answer (score 0):

Remus,

What about something like this:

```
private void infoDataGridView_CellValueChanged(object sender, DataGridViewCellEventArgs e)
{
   dataTable.Rows[e.RowIndex].ItemArray[e.ColumnIndex] = infoDataGridView.Rows[e.RowIndex].Cells[e.ColumnIndex].Value;
   UpdateChart();
}
```

The advantage here is to update your data table and your chart without touching the datagridview (so you don't have to worry about the edit mode etc).

Answer (score 0):

Instead of validating the whole datagridview again, could you just commit the changes and begin them again, so something like this:

```
void Control_KeyUp(object sender, KeyEventArgs e)
{
   dataGridView1.EndEdit();
   UpdateChart();
   dataGridView1.BeginEdit(false);
}
```